# remote desktop disconnects when i connect to vpn on remote server

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop

I have a VPS running windows server 2012 R2. I need to connect to a VPN throw L2TP on this machine.

I connect to this server with remote desktop and everything is good. Also I created VPN connection. But when I enter VPN username and password and press connect, remote desktop hangs and disconnects instantly. And server needs to reboot to use again.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Seriusly, nobody knows?

Comment: Looks like this one:
[VPN within RDP session](https://serverfault.com/questions/193308/vpn-within-a-remote-desktop-session)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VPN within a Remote Desktop session](https://serverfault.com/questions/193308/vpn-within-a-remote-desktop-session)

Comment: Thank you but that question even does't have a verified answer. I've seen that before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved. By unchecking "Use default gateway" in IPv4 and IPv6 settings of VPN properties.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. I don't have a "Use default gateway on remote network" checkbox to check. There is a solid workaround: use an alternate method to remote into the machine like GoToMyPC. It uses a different method of connecting, and in my case I was able to connect with it and then initiate the VPN connection without trouble.